# KB3022345 utc.app.json & telemetry - Patch not sticking

Tags: windows-7, file-corruption, sfc

I have a Windows 7 laptop that keep crashing to blue screen.

This has been happening intermittently for 3-4 weeks. After looking online I ran an "sfc /scannow" to check for corrupt files. The scan found 2 corrupt files - "utc.app.json" and "telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" - which it couldn't repair.

After a little more searching, I found http://thetechcookbook.com/windows-8-update-kb3022345-causing-corrupt-files/ which shows how to repair the files. I ran the patch and it worked! It stopped crashing.

However, today the patch seems to have undone itself. Another scan revealed that the same two files are corrupted. I've run the patch again to keep it going for the time being.

What can I do to stop Windows thinking it knows best and replacing this file with a broken one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[3022345](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3022345) has been replaced with [3068708](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3068708).

As both KB articles state:

> This update contains the following two manifests that are occasionally
>   updated by the Diagnostic Tracking Service:
>
> ```
> telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json
> utc.app.json
> ```
>
> The two files are marked as static files in the update. When an
>   advanced user runs the System File Checker Tool (sfc.exe), the files
>   are unintentionally flagged as corrupted. There is no impact or actual
>   corruption on a device that is running this update, and this issue
>   will be fixed in a later service update.

If it bothers you a lot just uninstall the update. All it does is backport the new Windows 10 Diagnostics Tracking Service to older Windows versions, and Windows 7 has managed without it for 6 years now.

Comment: I disagree with this: *There is no impact or actual corruption on a device that is running this update* While these files are being detected as corrupted the computer crashes regularly.

Comment: @Prinsig: That's what MS says. Anyway, how do you know your BSODs are connected to these two 'corrupted' files? What is your actual BSOD error text and code? You can confirm whether this update is at fault by uninstalling it as I've already noted above.

Comment: because they don't happen when the patch is applied to these two files. It turns out that 3068708 overwrote the patch that was applied on 3022345. So marking this as the answer for providing this information. Thanks a lot.